# Android Gesture API, need better responsiveness for onGesturePerformed ()

Tags: android, android-gesture

The Android Gesture API is a real help and removes the need to reimplement a pretty complex wheel.

I however need the API to be more "responsive".

As way of an example. Lets say I define a Gesture, such as "Circle" in which a single finger gesture event is defined to be, yep you guessed it, a single finger circle.

If the user undertakes this gesture continuously, without lifting the finger, I would like for "onGesturePerformed ()" to be called repeatedly, ie the user continues to perform the same gesture.

I would like a firing granularity of maybe 1/4 second. I have seen a similar question but in that case the user wanted a longer delay and not a shorter delay where the user does not lift the finger.

Many thanks in advance.

Paul